# Cachegrind - модуль Valgrind

Tags: c, unix, valgrind

Посыл каждого модуля Валгринд понятен, за исключением Кэшгринд.
Как я понял из мауналов

Модуль используется

1. Для сбора информации о статистике попадания в кэши процессора данных и инструкций программы.
2. Для сбора статистики работы модуля предсказания ветвления в программах.

Возникли вопросы

1. Я понимаю что кэши проца нужны для того чтобы он как то автоматически оптимизировался и делал некоторые вещи быстрее за счет сохранения некоторой инфы в кэше. Но! Разве мы как то можем повлиять на это? Судя по тому что Кэшгринд это профайлер, то по идее это как то можно сделать, получив инфу, но как? И как вообще понять что у нас есть потенциал увеличить нагрузку на кэши проца нашей программой (т.е. сказать процу использовать кеши активнее при работе с нашей прогой что ли)
2. Если есть инфа по работе модуля ветвлений, которая каким то образом говорит нам что этот модуль отработал плохо, то как мы можем изменить ситуацию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как в случае с кешированием, так и в случае с блоком предсказания ветвлений, надо понимать типовые алгоритмы и устройство этих модулей. За подробностями от себя порекомендую обратиться к классике, *Таненбаум — «Архитектура компьютера»*. Но вопрос не про их устройство, так что здесь я ограничусь простыми примерами, где можно увидеть их действие.

#### Про кеширование

Есть несколько эффектов, которое кеширование оказывает на реальное время выполнение. Оптимизация программы в этом плане почти всегда сводится к тому, чтобы использовать те алгоритмы, которые хорошо сочетаются с оным. Самый значительный параметр при этом — локальность данных, но есть и целый шлейф других эффектов связанных с устройством кешей, которые дают схожие проблемы.

Простой пример алгоритма, который плохо сочетается с кешированием — обход матрицы по столбцам:

```
#define SZ 2048

// размер матрицы 16MB ≥L3 на большинстве процессоров.
int matr[SZ][SZ];

// ...

for (int j=0; j<SZ; j++) {
  for (int i=0; i<SZ; i++) {
    matr[i][j]++;
  }
}
```

Если просто поменять местами внешний и внутренний цикл, то время выполнения значительно уменьшится. (Иногда, компилятор может сделать это сам.)

Вообще с кешированием плохо сочетается весь класс задач, где нужен произвольный доступ к большим объёмам данных: сюда входят многие алгоритмы связанные с использованием деревьев, графов, хеш-таблиц и т.д.; зачастую для исправления ситуации можно выбрать другой алгоритм или изменить текущий, иногда можно улучшить ситуацию перераспределив данные в памяти, например, создав специальный аллокатор; обычно и то и другое требует дополнительного исследования. На практике до этого мало у кого доходят руки.

#### Про блок предсказаний ветвления.

Здесь свободы намного меньше, а выигрыш зависит от архитектуры.

При статическом предсказании может помочь правильная подготовка кода на этапе компиляции. В частности (на примере `gcc`):

- Эвристики и встроенные оптимизации компилятора.
- Профилирование с помощью встроенного в gcc профилировщика (см. ключи `-fprofile-arcs` и [`-fbranch-probabilities`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-fbranch-probabilities)). AFAIK данные от `valgrind`'а пока нельзя напрямую скормить `gcc`.
- Ручная расстановка макросов [__builtin_expect](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#index-_005f_005fbuiltin_005fexpect)
- Форматирование кода: например в операторе `if-then-else` блок `then` обычно считается наиболее вероятным.

Но на архитектурах с динамическими предсказаниями (например i686+ [да поправят меня, может и на i586]) эффект от этих приёмов минимален и ими имеет смысл пользоваться только в относительно редко вызываемом, но крайне критичном по времени коде, например, в обработчиках прерываний. Для кода общего назначения обычно ничего сделать нельзя/бессмысленно, за исключением разве что предподготовки данных. Например, следующий код будет работать заметно быстрее на [почти]отсортированном массиве, чем на случайном именно за счёт блока предсказаний:

```
int arr[SZ];
// ...
int threshold = 42;
size_t cnt = 0;

for (size_t i; i<SZ; ++i) {
  if (arr[i]>threshold) {
    cnt++;
  }
}
```

#### Замечание о `valgrind`'е

Стоит заметить, что `valgrind` не опирается на запрос какой-либо статистике у процессора, а просто симулирует работу кеша и блока предсказаний, так что результаты его работы могут отличаться от исполнения на реальном ЦП, но с определённой долей достоверности их вполне можно использовать для оценки и оптимизации.